# Express route with param not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple express routes below.

```
const express = require('express');
const api = express.Router();

api.get('/vacancies', vacancies.getAllVacancies);

api.get('/vacancy/:id', vacancies.getVacancyById);
```

I intend to use `req.params.id` in `getVacancyById` .  However, `getAllVacancies` works , but calling the path

```
/vacancy/?id=1 is never recognized . I tried vacancy?id=1 many things it just never get called. The route is not recognized at all.
```

Please what am i doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There are three type of prams that can be sent. Body, resource and query parameters. Your I'd is a resource param but you are calling your api with a query param. Call it as /vacancy/1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would propose 2 solutions for this issue:

Solution 1 **(recommended)**:
Use `api.get('/vacancy/:id', ...` & `req.params.id` and access via `/vacancy/1`

Solution 2:
Use `api.get('/vacancy', ...` & `req.query.id` and access via `/vacancy/?id=1`

Answer (score 5):

because your /?id is a query parameter. to get the value of id use req.query.id
OR if you want the value of id in req.params the your url should be /vacancy/1  instead of /vacancy/?id=1

Comment: What about the route. It doesn't get called.

Comment: have you tried hitting on /vacancy/1 ? and it doesn't get called because you are probably hitting on the wrong url